# GZIP compression with unicode in drupal

Tags: drupal, unicode, gzip

I have a website in hindi/marathi language and I have applied gzip in drupal. But somehow it is not working for all pages. I did check it on http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php , it shows 'yes' for gzip and web page compression.I cannot see problem occuring there. Can anyone tell how to enable support for unicode in drupal?
I am a newbie in drupal. Please help.